# Understanding hash functions.

Tags: cryptography, hash-function

What I understand by a Hash function, is a function $H$, such that taking an input $x$ of some bit-length  $L$, produces an output $y$ of some bit-length $l$ such that $L >> l$ (where ">>" means that "much more bigger"). So that we have $H(x)=y$.

The doubt is that sometimes I saw that $H$ instead of taking one input $x$, it takes various inputs, say $x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n$ (without even specifying how many inputs or even changing the number of inputs they are giving to $H$ depending on the situation).

What I think is that they just do $x_1\|x_2\|x_3\| \dots\|x_i = x$ (so they pad all of the $x_i$'s and call $x$ to the result), where $i \in \{2, \dots, n\}$. Is that correct? In that case, just by reordering the $x_i$'s would change the output of the hash function $H$; so the order of the inputs matter.

Also, what it means a base hash (normally denoted by $Q$) and extended base hash (normally denoted by $\overline{Q}$?

All of this is based on the well-known **SHA-256**.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we donate a hash by $H:\{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^h$ where * is the Kleene star means 0 or more $h$ is the output size like 256 in SHA256

**Merkle Damgård (MD) construction**: SHA series, expect the SHA3 which is based on Sponge Construction, is based on the [Merkle Damgård (MD) construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction).

**Compression function:** In MD, there is a compression function $C$  which is usually a simple block cipher with lots of iteration, that takes the input of the previous value and the current message block as the key, and output is the encryption. $$C:\{0,1\}^{256}\times \{0,1\}^{512}\to \{0,1\}^{256}$$

**Padding:** Let the message size is $\ell$. For SHA256, the message padded first add 1, then smallest $k$ zero bits, then the 64-bit encoded $\ell$ is added so that $$\ell +1+ k \equiv 448 \bmod 512.$$

**Message processing:** for each is divided 512-bit parts, each  message block is contributed into the hashing as;

$$C_i = C(H_{i-1}, m_{i})$$ and

$$C_0 = (constants, m_{0}).$$ The constants can be found on [NIST.FIPS.180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf).

**The Hash:** $$H(m) = C_{t-1}$$ where $t$ is the number of block of the padded mesage.

> In that case, just by reordering the xi's would change the output of the hash function H; so the order of the inputs matter.

Yes, reordering will change the result. However, SHA-1 and SHA-2 are vulnerable to length extension attacks like any MD based hash function.

Comment: So what it means when they use different amount of variables in the input of the hash function? It is what I said?

Comment: Normally a hash function takes an input $m$ and pads ... rest as in answer for MD based. That is by the definition. If someone uses like $Hash(m_1\mathbin\| m_2 \cdots \mathbin\| m_l)$ they are preprocess some messages to hash. This can be considered like Tar an archive and hash it. This is what I understood from your writing. If you provide a link where you saw that, we can consider more precisely.